# service or strategy to detect if users enter fake names?

Tags: c#, java, php, python, api

Im searching about services/strategies to detect when entered names in forms are spammy, example: asdasdasd, ksfhaiodsfh, wpoeiruopwieru, zcpoiqwqwea. crazy keyboard inputs.

I am trying akismet is not specially for names (http://kemayo.wordpress.com/2005/12/02/akismet-py/).

thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have a very hard time with this, because many people have names from foreign languages that to you might simply look like randomly hitting the keyboard.  Many people also have custom, unique names that no one else has--particularly in the United States, where there are no rules on that sort of thing.

Comment: You need an exhaustive list of names.  There is always going to be someone who doesn't fit. This sort of thing appears on http://thedailywtf.com/Series/Error_0x27_d.aspx all the time so have a look and it might help you decide what to do.

Answer (score 2):

One strategy is having a black list with weird names and/or a white list with normal names, to reject/accept names. But it can be difficult to found it.

Answer (score 1):

you could look for unusual character combinations like many consecutive vowels/consonants, and watch your registrations and create a list of recurring patterns (like asd) in false names

i would refrain from automatically block those inputs and rather mark them for examination

Answer (score 0):

Ask for a real email and send info to connect there. Then get info from the account.

No way is really safe anyway.

Comment: I am asking for person names not emails.

Comment: how do you get real names from an e-mail address?

Comment: @logoff Take a look at [email](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr)

Answer (score 0):

If speed isn't an issue, download a list of the top 100k most common names, throw them in an O(1) lookup data structure, see if the input is there, and if not, you could always compare the input to the entries using a string similarity algorithm.
Although if you do, you will probably want to bucket by starting letter to prevent having to perform that calculation on the entire list.